# SignalR not working with IIS 8

Tags: .net, signalr, iis-8

I have an application with SignalR it works perfectly with IIS 7 but the same code on IIS 8 is not working.

This is the error I get:

> jquery.signalR-2.2.0.min.js:8 WebSocket connection to 'ws://xx.xx.xx.xxx/SignalRPreLive/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=%2BBSPzYRBKtW6nYefmb%2BBXsMGOO6%2B1parXE5iSf5w0LhdWnsTYElhIrwOlvmDSZhURC8J8EoZX%2FSqFryNziX8qBY7k1mMPbdQCW64vus4voh7KLg%2BXbhqqrPJjVNEdDjV&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22pushnotificationhub%22%7D%5D&tid=7' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500

Comment: check whether the installed all the required roles
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26945710/signalr-always-falls-to-long-polling-in-the-production-server

Comment: Are you sure websockets are enabled on the server? They are disabled by default.